# Is there are reason to have tables, views,etc in dbo folder vs Schema Objects folder in database project

Tags: visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

I have older projects, where all of the DDL files are under Project/Schema Objects, and a newly created project where all of the DDL files were created under Project/dbo/.  Is there a functional difference, or is there a standard convention on which to use?  All of the other projects that I am working on use Schema Objects.

Just to be clear, the tables and everything are in the dbo schema in both cases.  It's only the structure that I am wondering about.

Answer (score 0):

the `dbo` folder actually is a schema. The `database_owner` schema to be specific. It has to do with the databases architecture, but it's nothing you have to worry about. Just make sure to leave the hierarchy that way.

Answer (score 0):

The folder structure doesn't really matter too much. The older VS DB Projects used a more detailed structure. That was simplified when SSDT was released.  If you want consistency, you can always import the schema from the current DB and port over the older structures (pre/post-deploy scripts and anything else custom).  However, the folder structure is somewhat arbitrary. You're not required to use any set structure - it just makes project organization easier.